# Admin user not showing directory path in console prompt, only $

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, non-root-user

I have an Ubuntu server that I administer through `ssh`. When I login as `root` I get a full path in the prompt, like `/var/www`. I created a user with sudo privileges for the purpose of administration. When I login, all I see in the command prompt is a `$` sign. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Look inside root's `/root/.bashrc` file or the global `/etc/bash.bashrc` file to see the value of the `PS1` variable for the `root` user and the system's defaults, respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is controlled by the `PS1` environment variable. You can see what this is by running, as root, `echo $PS1`. You can then set the variable in your own bash profile with `echo 'PS1=<value of PS1>' >> ~/.bashrc`.

You can google for lots of possible values of `PS1`, but the part you are currently missing is `\w` for working directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you see just `$` as a prompt, it's most likely that you're running dash. [Dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell) is a stripped-down shell with little more than [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard features. It's intended to run scripts, and it's more efficient (both in terms of memory and in terms of processor speed) than bash. Dash doesn't have any fancy interactive feature. Under Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`.

If you intend to log in as that user interactively, I recommend changing your login shell to bash:

```
chsh -s bash
```

Comment: (+) or `chsh -s /bin/bash` worked for me.

Comment: And don't forget to reboot before seeing the results. Thanks guys!